# Cant remove line that appears above page content

Tags: page-template

Hi all I am running a multisite. I have custom page templates that are working fine, however the home page displays the text shown below:

```
2" class="hentry p1 page publish author-jonkino untagged is-full
comments-closed pings-closed y2012 m05 d18 h23 slug-home">
```

I am sure it's not in the template and I am struggling to find where its coming from. Any direction as to what might be calling it would be gratefully received.

http://www.secretgardensfestival.net/secretkino/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing part of your post `<div>` Look through your loop and you'll see something that's not closed or something.

It will more than likely look like this

```
<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

When it needs to be something like

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Hope that helps.